# Create a socket server on an iPhone without using proxy server or bonjour

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets

I want to transfer data from one iPhone to another using sockets.

I have seen a lot of examples of connecting 2 iPhones together. either using sockets or using bonjour. I don't want to connect the devices using bonjour. For sockets, all examples I have encountered are using a server (non-ios device) for communication.

My question is: Can I create a socket server on an iOS device? If yes, can anyone share some pointers plz?

Answer (score 0):

Found this library [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket). It has 2 example codes. one, which creates a socket server on one device and the other which creates the socket client.